# How to make all ResNet50 layers appear in model.summary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I want to see all the ResNet50 layers and not the resnet50 block in `model.summary`. I saw a similar issue [How can I use tf.keras.Model.summary to see the layers of a child model which in a father model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657003/how-can-i-use-tf-keras-model-summary-to-see-the-layers-of-a-child-model-which-in), but I'm having difficulties in adapting it to my model since it uses ResNet50 instead of MobileNet.

This is my model:

```
Resnet = ResNet101(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
model = tf.keras.Sequential(Resnet)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=no_classes, activation="softmax"))
```

This is the code I have right now based on the previous issue.

```
class ResNet50(tf.keras.Sequential):
    def __init__(self, input_shape=(224, 224, 3), classes=8):
        super(ResNet50, self).__init__()
        self.backbone_model = [layer for layer in
               tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(input_shape, include_top=False, pooling='avg').layers]
        self.classificator = tf.keras.layers.Dense(classes,activation='relu', name='classificator')

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = inputs
        for layer in self.backbone_model:
            x = layer(x)
        x = self.classificator(x)
        return x
model = ResNet50()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=no_classes, activation="softmax"))
```

How do I initialize it with `imagenet` weights? is it done automatically? Is the pooling `average` and the activation `relu` for Resnet50? Do I have to add more layers?

Answer (score 1):

The model has a `layers` parameter so try to run this loop. I don't remember exactly but if `model.layers` is a list then.

```
summary = []
for layer, value in zip(model.layers, model.summary()):
 try:
   summary.append(layer.summary())
 except:
   summary.append(value)
```

you might need to modify it but it should be something similar.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful. Although it shows all of the resnet50 layers, it stopped showing the layers I add after that, namely the softmax, the global pooling and the dropout layers. Do you have any idea what could be the problem?